# How to generate barcodes in excel worksheet

Tags: excel, barcode, vba

Just a short question, how to generate a barcode in excel worksheet? The barcode-text has been specified in a cell.

(Not intent to mass generate barcodes which otherwise can be done in MS Word.)

Comment: Just install a barcode font?

Comment: @Comintern Yup, good point, but i don't want to ask everyone to install something...

Comment: If you don't want to install a font you'd have to somehow generate a bitmap with the barcode. However, using a barcode font _is_ easier in the end imho, you could use something like this https://github.com/BdR76/barcode128.bas

Answer (score 4):

Select the range where barcode-text is written:

[image]

Then run the following script:

```
Sub INSERT_BARCODE()
    Const BarcodeWidth As Integer = 156
    Dim ws As Worksheet, WdApp
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With WdApp.Documents.Add
        .PageSetup.RightMargin = .PageSetup.PageWidth - .PageSetup.LeftMargin - BarcodeWidth
        .Fields.Add(Range:=.Range, Type:=-1, Text:="DISPLAYBARCODE " & CStr(Selection.Value) & " CODE39 \d \t", PreserveFormatting:=False).Copy
    End With
    ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    WdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=False
    Set WdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Note:

- Change the encoding rule as you like. This example uses `CODE39` rule. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745901(v=office.12).aspx for more details.
- Adjust the `BarcodeWidth` interger to best fit the barcode.

BR~

Comment: I get an `Error! Bookmark not defined` message on running that code.

Comment: i must be missing something on the word.application part. I'm doing it on Excel/Word 2013. you are on 2010?

Comment: Yes I am on Word 2010.

Comment: i did not go into detailed research. but according to MSDN this method doesn't work on word 2010. i can't remember where i read one article, it could be WORD 2010 just not using 'DISPLAYBARCODE` but something else. i can't remember...

Comment: @JaneksBergs.. not if one work in a finance team where software installation are generally blocked unless you get approval to do so, so have to work within the limited resource.

Answer (score 2):

This is massively over-specced for what you need, but you can pull the bits out of it as required.

```
Sub Call_Barcode_Service()

Dim strResource As String
Dim strSize As String
Dim iHgt As Integer
Dim iWth As Integer
Dim iGap As Integer
Dim PictureGrab As String
Dim lngLastRow As Long

strSize = UCase(InputBox("How Big?", "Small, Medium or Large?", "L"))

Select Case strSize

    Case Is = "S"
        iWth = 150
        iHgt = 45
        iGap = 3


    Case Is = "M"
        iWth = 150
        iHgt = 60
        iGap = 4

    Case Is = "L"
        iWth = 240
        iHgt = 75
        iGap = 5

    Case Else
        iWth = 250
        iHgt = 75
        iGap = 5

End Select


Set sel = Selection.SpecialCells(xlTextValues)

Set news = Worksheets.Add()
news.Name = "Barcodes"
Set op = news.Range("A1")

For Each acc In sel
strResource = acc.Value

PictureGrab = "http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=" & strResource & "&style=197&type=C128B&width=" & iWth & "&height=" & iHgt & "&xres=1&font=1"

Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, op.Left, op.Top, iWth, iHgt)

With sh

.Name = strResource
.Line.Visible = False
.Fill.UserPicture PictureGrab

End With

Set op = op.Offset(iGap + 1, 0).Range("A1")

Next

Range("G1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: nice one. i like this as well, works on all office version. but need internet connection unless the picture was made static.

Comment: Yes, that's the one caveat that it needs internet access. I used the code to run **hundreds** of rows of data and also generated QR codes using a similar bit of `VBA` to show the difference in data density between barcodes and QR. Like I say, over-specced for one cell! :o)

Answer (score -2):

I use word with Macro :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Test Barcode
'
Dim codei As String
Dim codej As String

    For I = 1 To 1 '0
    For J = 1 To 2 '0
        codei = CStr(I)
        While Len(codei) < 2
           codei = "0" & codei
        Wend
        codej = CStr(J)
        While Len(codej) < 4
           codej = "0" & codej
        Wend
        codei = codei & codej
        Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
        PreserveFormatting:=False
    Selection.TypeText Text:="DisplayBarcode " & codei & " Code128 \t"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Fields.Update
    Next J
    Next I
End Sub
```